# Not resolving a factory service with http within & ui-router before controller is called

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using Angular.js, ui-router, a UserService Factory and a controller.

The problem I have is that when my resolv returns in the route it is not fully resolved when the controller is activated.

This is my UserService:

```
app.factory('UserService',["$rootScope","$q","$http","$window",function($rootScope,$q,$http,$window) {
    var accountinfo;
    return {
        getCurrentAccount: function() {
            $http.get("/api/v1/accounts").then(function(data){
                accountinfo=data;
                return data;
            })
    }
```

And this is the state in my route:

```
.state("in",{
    url:"/in",
    templateUrl: "/templates/in.html",
    authenticate: true,
    controller: "inController",
    resolve: {
        servicename: 'UserService',
        accountinfo: function(servicename) {
            return servicename.getCurrentAccount();
        }
    }
})
```

On this for a week. I have done a lot of reading and research. I have been unable to resolve this. No pun intended!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to return a promise to the resolve function for a route to wait until the promise is resolved. Your `getCurrentAccount()` should return the result of the `$http` request:

```
getCurrentAccount: function() {
    return $http.get("/api/v1/accounts").then(function(result){
        accountinfo = result.data;
        return result.data;
    });
}
```

Comment: I am confused on this.  I was under the impression resolve was used to avoid using $http requests.

Comment: `resolve` is simply used as a way of waiting until a promise is resolved before loading the route. You can return any promise to it (i.e. your own, or one from `$http`).

Comment: Thanks for the clarification